# Only show hidden files in certain directories

Tags: macos, unix, filesystems

On a Unix system (or more specifically on [Mac OS X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X)) is it possible to show hidden files in only some directories? For example as a developer I want to see the hidden files 
in my [Ruby on Rails](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails) projects but not on my desktop as well.

I guess I'm just tired of seeing all these `.DS_Store` and `.trashes` files swimming around, any remedies not directly related are welcome too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening your project directory with a text editor such as TextMate (Great for RoR!), shows you all the files.

If not, it may be useful to add ".*|" at the beginning of the file pattern you will find in TextMate's Preferences > Advanced > File Pattern:

P.S. I'm not aware of any way to show invisible files only for a given directory. But i would rather not do it if it is possible. I prefer working with the terminal for this sort of things. It's even cooler with TextMate's Command line tool, type:

```
$ mate any_file_or_directory
```

...to open it in TextMate

Answer (score 2):

Undirectly related solutions welcome?

Well, I recently came across [this tutorial](http://artofgeek.com/2009/09/16/toggle-display-of-hidden-files-in-finder-with-keyboard-shortcut/) which allows you to use the Shift-Cmd-Period shortcut that's already usable in open/save dialog boxes inside Finder as well. It *does* involve restarting Finder, but since all the windows are all restored it's relatively seamless.

Quite stupid that Finder doesn't have such functionality built in if the open/save dialogs do have such functionality, but ah well.

Answer (score 1):

you can write a shell script, eg with bash

```
shopt -s dotglob
for file in my_rails_directory1/.*  my_rails_directory2/.*
do
 echo $file
done
```

Comment: `dotglob` is pointless when you manually use `.*`

Comment: i leave it there in case OP want to list all files, not only hidden

Answer (score 1):

Does not do precisely what you want, but I use the [hiddenfiles widget](http://www.apple.com/downloads/dashboard/developer/hiddenfiles.html) to toggle visibility. This affects all folders off course, but it's quick to use.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - sort of. Just some folders?! Interesting idea.

**Symlink to the hidden dir**

```
 ln -s ~/.ssh ~/ssh
```

this will put an alias type folder you can double click to ~/.ssh etc

**Command Period in Finder**
Hit [command]-[period] together to show hidden files like the screenshot.
Then double clicking on say..... .ssh directory

**Resource Fork**
Try to create a resource fork for the hidden directory.

**In the Terminal**
To just show hidden dirs try:

```
ls -A | grep '^\.'
```

That will list all files, including those that start with a period. Grep will filter it to only show lines starting with a dot. 
[image: Command period also works in file dialogs to show hidden. They appear a bit ghostly and pale.]