# How do I list only hidden directories in mac/linux terminal?

Tags: macos, command-line

Got bored of guessing after this:

```
ls -A | grep -E ^.
```

I thought the regex caret `^` is supposed to mean "line starts with". I was hoping to use a regular expression like `^.` to match only files that start with a dot... But I still see regular files not just hidden directories (those dirs that start with a period such as .ssh and .config).

Would be a dupe of the un-answered: [Only show hidden files in certain directories](https://superuser.com/questions/121676/only-show-hidden-files-in-certain-directories)

Example correct output:

```
.aws
.bash_history
.bashrc
.cache
.cloud-locale-test.skip
.config
.dbshell
.gnupg
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the `.` when passing it to grep, otherwise it will be interpreted as "any character". grep accepts `\` to escape characters. However, the shell also uses `\` to escape, so you'll need to put the whole pattern in single quotes:

```
ls -a | grep '^\.'
```

Comment: YES! The dot. How foolish of I. Thanks!

Comment: That was (maybe?) the worlds fastest correct answer on Stack! 5min gap!

Answer (score 2):

The first answer from @mikel is correct, but a shorter alternative is `ls -ad .*`.  It's easier to remember too (for me), although it does include "." and ".." in the output.  You could use `ls -ad .??*` to make sure those don't show up, but that's a little harder to remember.